# Relay Substitution

Tags: rf, relay, latching-relay

I somewhat understand the difference between 1-coil and 2-coil latching relays but I want to double check before I spend a bit of money ordering my circuits.

Would I be able to replace [HF3 71](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-PB/HF3-71?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsqIr59i2oRcpmhgZmxO7wzG295OjHPpRk%3D) with [HF3 91](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-PB/HF3-91?qs=LU7oW20kJpPNp%2FTMt0J30Q%3D%3D) ([datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification%20Or%20Standard%7F108-98021%7F0317%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_108-98021_0317.pdf%7F2-1462051-4) for both) by tying the reset + and - together for the coils and more or less treating it like a 1-coil relay?

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet drawings are fairly ridiculous. Contact TE support for details. It’s on them to help their customers. Otherwise buy someone else’s parts. You should definitely request samples and try it out.

But the way it works generally is as follows:

- single coil requires a full H bridge driver, since you need to apply positive and negative voltage across it;
- double coils require just one active device per coil - usually an NPN transistor or N-MOS device; they are designed for unipolar drive, similar to 4-coil stepper motors.

The double coil is a trade off: higher physical complexity for a lower driver circuit complexity.

You should not be connecting double coils together. Connect their + end to supply, and their - end to a low-side driver. The cheapest general purpose NPN transistor you can find in surface mount will do the job usually.